# how do i filter out data that is within 5 minutes of each other?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to generate data for a report. in this report i am monitoring the number of unique calls that were dropped by clients, however if a client calls and disconnects every minute I need to see that as 1 call. we have decided to illuminate all calls that happen within 5 minutes of the first call.

My data looks like

```
CREATE_DATE_TIME|Number

2019-06-03 09:10:56.0|100037729

2019-06-03 09:10:57.0|100037729

2019-06-03 09:10:58.0|100134657

2019-06-03 09:10:59.0|101401435

2019-06-03 09:11:00.0|101401435

2019-06-03 09:11:01.0|104925349
```

and I want

```
2019-06-03 09:10:56.0   100037729

2019-06-03 09:10:58.0   100134657

2019-06-03 09:10:59.0   101401435

2019-06-03 09:11:01.0   104925349
```

So I tried to use a Datediff to eliminate the additional ones only to get more duplications.

```
    SELECT Distinct [CREATE_DATE_TIME]
          ,right(Left([SUBJECT],16),11) as [Number] 
          --,datediff(mi,[CREATE_DATE_TIME],lag ([CREATE_DATE_TIME],1) over (order by [CREATE_DATE_TIME])) as timeprev
          --,CAse when datediff(mi,[CREATE_DATE_TIME],lag ([CREATE_DATE_TIME],1) over (order by [CREATE_DATE_TIME]))>5 then 'Unique' else 'Duplicate' end as [Time_dup_check]
    From [server1].[Database].[Schema].[call_list]

    Where datediff(mi,[CREATE_DATE_TIME],lag ([CREATE_DATE_TIME],1) over (order by [CREATE_DATE_TIME])) > 5
```

This was the final Result :(

```
CREATE_DATE_TIME|Number

2019-06-03 09:10|100037729

2019-06-03 09:10|100037729

2019-06-11 08:02|100134657

2019-06-11 08:02|100134657

2019-06-13 12:58|101401435

2019-06-13 12:58|101401435

2019-06-13 12:59|101401435

2019-06-13 12:59|101401435

2019-06-18 14:35|104925349

2019-06-18 14:35|104925349
```

Can someone please help me filter this ?

Comment: Your query does not return anything resembling your sample data, so your question is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select cl.*
from (select cl.*,
             lag(create_date_time) over (partition by number order by create_date_time) as prev_created_date_time
      from [server1].[Database].[Schema].[call_list] cl
     ) cl
where prev_created_date_time is null or
      prev_created_date_time < dateadd(minute, -5, create_date_time)
```